# Why does process child execute some unexpected line?

Tags: c, process, parent-child

So I'm getting to know how processes work and have written some simple code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
int SemId;
void SemGet(int n)
{
   SemId = semget(IPC_PRIVATE, n, 0600);
   if (SemId == -1) {
      exit(1);
   }
}
int SemSetVal(int SemNum, int SemVal)
{
   return semctl(SemId, SemNum, SETVAL, SemVal);
}
int SemOp(int SemNum, int SemOp)
{
   struct sembuf SemBuf;
   SemBuf.sem_num = SemNum;
   SemBuf.sem_op  = SemOp;
   SemBuf.sem_flg = 0;
   return semop(SemId, & SemBuf, 1);
}
void SemRemove(void)
{
   (void) semctl(SemId, 0, IPC_RMID, 0);
}

void child(int vchild) {
    printf("\nChild %d", vchild);
    return;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    printf("\nHeeeyoooo!");

    if (fork() == 0) {
        child(1);
        exit(0);
    }
    (void) wait(NULL);
    printf("\nParent.");

    return 0;
}
```

and what I get for output is

```
Heeeyoooo!
Child 1Heeeyoooo!
Parent.
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.001 s
Press ENTER to continue.
```

Why do I get "heyooo" twice?
I seems like the child is getting back into the main instead of getting terminated by the exit...

Comment: use `printf("Child %d\n", child);`

Comment: well, `\C` should produce error. `exit()` should be in `stdlib.h`. `fork()` is in `unistd.h`. what you're upto ? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`child is getting back into the main instead of getting terminated by the exit`..no, that's not the case.

There are many issues with your code.

1. `\Child` will give you error in terms of "unknown escape sequence", change to `\nChild`.
2. include `stdlib.h` for `exit()`.
3. include `unistd.h` for `fork()`
4. add `\n` to `printf("Heeeyoooo!");` to flush the output buffer.

After 1,2 and 3, the *main* problem in your code is, there is no `newline escape sequence` present in your `printf()` which is why your output buffer is not flushed. So, to flush out the standard output buffer before next print, add a newline escape sequence [`\n`] which will flush the buffer.

Worth of mentioning, from the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fork) of `fork()`

> The child process shall have its own copy of the parent's open
>   directory streams. Each open directory stream in the child process may
>   share directory stream positioning with the corresponding directory
>   stream of the parent

which means, without the flushing of the buffer, `Heeeyoooo!` is still present in child's output stream and hence it is printed again.

Comment: Those are all some quick edit errors,  the code compiles in codeblocks on gcc

Comment: Is /n always a viable flush for stdbuff?

Comment: @DominikDitoIvosevic as i mentioned, point 4 is the _prime_ issue. others are issues. :-)

Comment: @DominikDitoIvosevic it's `\n`. not `/n`, its `stdout`, not `stdbuff`. I don't know what you mean by viable, but other escape sequences like `\t` would also work.

Comment: Why do you think an escape sequence (which is a compile time thing) causes a flush at runtime?

Comment: @AlanStokes AFAIK, without the terminating `\n`, the contains of the output buffer will not be flushed to the output. and I missed the `newline` part in writing but provided in the code `\nChild`. However, updated. is it ok now?

Answer (score 2):

If you write

```
printf("Heeeyoooo!");
fflush(stdout);
```

and then fork, the error goes away. The reason is that `fork()` clones the output buffer for stdout while `"Heeeyoooo!"` is still in it, so it is subsequently printed twice.